# Cannot resolve class from the same package (java)

Tags: java, import

I've created a project and I want to use other project's classes. I added a project which I wanted to import to the libraries of the current project, but nothing happens. When I start to type the name of the class to import, IDEA suggests it, but when I click the suggestion, it writes down the name of the class with a qualified name and highlights it with red. When I click the name of the class to import in the qualified name nothing happens. Don't know what to do with it. The same operations work with other projects.

Comment: What kind of projects do you have? maven? sbt? Since you mentioned you use an IDEA have you tried adding an external library more or less like a jar ? If it's a maven project, have you simply tried including the project in your dependency with scope System?

Comment: As far as I understood yor question, I think this has nothing to do with java imports. Instead what you need can be something connected to IntelliJ. Here is a post about something I think is related to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31342689/how-do-i-use-classes-from-another-project-in-intellij-idea