# How to use classes from one project in another project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am building a custom Java library. I keep most of my "repeated" codes there, like file handling, string processing, etc. Each time I want to use them, I have to copy and paste the class into the other project(s) I'm on. Is there a way I can make this custom library class into a "dependency"? I'm using IntelliJ as my IDE.

Comment: You should take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31342689/how-do-i-use-classes-from-another-project-in-intellij-idea).

Comment: yes i did @Filippo but I dont understand what this means:
"Never use project class in another project, always create a nice interface and use that interface in other projects". and how to do it

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency.

Comment: Check also [this](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/library-in-java-best-practices.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add the master project as a jar (dependency) to your projects.

Comment: okay, I'm sorry if this is ultra noob-ish, but how do I do that?

Comment: You can check this thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project

Comment: It works, thanks

Comment: You are always welcome, happy to hear that it works.